# JavaScript each() is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "https://namu.wiki/w/크롤링";


request(url, function (err, res, html) {
    if (!err) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('.wiki-heading-content').each(function(){
            var post = {"content": "" };
            var data=$(this);
            post['content']=data.text();
            console.log(post);
        });
    }
});
```

The line of code below is not working. Why?

```
//$('.wiki-heading-content').each(function()
```

Comment: define "is not working": does it give an error, if so which one? Does it produce output that's different from the expected one?

Comment: The class selector $ ('. wiki-heading-content') in jQuery does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using jQuery in your code and you overwrite(in the function scope) your global jQuery object on this line.

`var $ = cheerio.load(html);`

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand it well. Could you explain it again?

Comment: When you initialise your jQuery library, it is stored in $ variable. On the line mentioned you override value of that variable which means you no longer have jQuery object as $ variable in that function scope and as such you cannot call jQuery methods because they are undefined